# Fact or opinion?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The book contains techniques that some people may find useful.

Can anyone give me some explanation on this sentence whether it's a fact or opinion.

Seems like a very basic question, but it really makes my head spin. For me, this is definitely a opinion. Because of the "some people may find useful" modifier, which signify that a sentence refered to such *techniques* isn't always true; they may or may not be useful to people. However, one stated otherwise. So I'm confused.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even if in reality not a *single* person finds *any* of the techniques useful, the statement is still "true" if the speaker doesn't *know* that. But actually, your example is just what we call a "hedge". I'm sure the writer at least *believes* that many people ***will*** find those techniques useful (or at least, they ***would*** if they read the book, which most people presumably won't do anyway). But the writer is probably "hedging / weakening" his assertive statement to make it easier for other people to accept, not because he doesn't really believe it himself.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I understand. Just like "Lola said something" is always true if *Lola* really said it. It's fact no matter what Lola said is true or not. But this sentence is a persuasion to make people interested in his book, or at least, his sole belief. Not a statement like "He believes that ..." or "He said that ..." Thus can't be consider as a fact. Am I right?

Comment: Well, consider [10 Celebs Who Actually Believe The Earth Is Flat](https://www.thetravel.com/10-celebs-who-actually-believe-the-earth-is-flat-10-who-believe-other-things/). I expect mostly that's just made-up drivel, but it's quite possible at least *some* of the "celebrities" referred to there really do believe the earth is flat. I don't know about the *specific* case of ***Kanye West believes the earth is flat***, but if he does, that ***highlighted statement*** is "true", regardless of whether the belief itself is true. Plus of course "truth" is a slippery concept if we live in a simulation!